# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'html'

Tags: javascript

```
function init() {
supportChat = $("#ChatWindow");
status = supportChat.find("#status");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    init();

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        status.html("Connected.");
        socket.emit('setuser', wm.id);
    });

});
```

На строке: **status.html("Connected.");** выдает сообщение

*Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'html'*
Не могу понять почему, если в init они инициализируются

Comment: []()

    console.log( [ status, typeof status ] )

Comment: ["[object Object]", "string"]

Comment: Сделайте инициализацию:  

    var status;

http://jsfiddle.net/eJdT7/

Comment: не помогло: ["", "string"]

Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'html'

Comment: крайне странное поведение...сделал console.log(status) и вижу что есть метод html. но так почему-то выдает ошибку